# Cannot browse external website with IE8 but still can with Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, virus, internet-explorer-8

Yesterday at my workplace something happened that meant that I could no longer visit any sites apart from from those within the company Intranet with IE8 any more. This also applies to Chrome, which leaves Firefox as the only browser that I have that can browse external sites.

What I have tried:

- restarting my computer several times
- reinstalling IE, but no luck with any of these approaches

I've also done some google searches, and found out that it could have being caused by virus that's affecting the internet options settings for IE. This would leave Firefox unaffected as Firefox doen't share its settings with IE

But the question is, what are the settings? And do I get IE working again?

Comment: Have you tried typing in IP addresses directly? Also, are you able to do an `nslookup` of some external sites? What happens when you try to go to these external sites?

Comment: Thanks Soandos for your recent response, I just tried to type in the ip address of google.com.au, still not working, but trying on firefox works. what happens when I try to go to google.com.au using IE8 is that it thinks for a long time before it finally display "The address is not valid"

Comment: Do the `ping` and `nslookup` commands work?

Comment: request timeout for pinging google.com.au, but nslookup for google.com.au seems to work

Comment: sorry the final display is "Internet Explorer cannot display webpage" instead of "The address is not valid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the IE Settings for proxy settings. Tools, Internet Options, Connections, LAN Settings, make sure that only "Automatic Detect Settings" is checked. also try to reset IE by going to Tools, Internet Options, Advanced tab and then reset button.
Also ask also your System Administrator if there were maybe group policy that redirect you to ISA Server and blocks you from surfing the Internet or any policy on the router.

Comment: Thanks Miro, good pick up, "Automatic Detect Settings" wasn't really checked. But when I do tick the check box only in LAN settings and restarted IE, still no luck :)

Comment: I also did reset the IE settings in the advanced tab, same symptom

Comment: Thanks Miro, you're right for the proxy settings. For some reason my all my proxy settings have gone.